# Android EditText inside ScrollView get auto focus

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, scrollview

I have a page that contains a main `ScrollView`, and within that there are 5 `EditText` controls and a few spinner controls.

Whenever I select some value in the spinner controls, the page scrolls automatically and the `EditText` gets the focus. How can I prevent this?

I have also tried calling the `clearfocus` method on the `EditText` that receives the autofocus, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Duplicate as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176391/stop-scrollview-from-auto-scrolling-to-an-edittext

Comment: I think the solution is here:
[Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup/8639921#8639921