# How to remove focus from EditText when user is done editing?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a single EditText on my layout. After the user inputs some text and hits the "done" key, I would like to remove the blinking cursor from it. I have scoured StackOverflow and found 3 answers that didn't work for me. The blinking cursor still remains.

```
private class MyOnKeyListener implements OnKeyListener {
  public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
    && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
      // FAIL 0
      MyActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.someOtherView).requestFocus();

      // FAIL 1
      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE
      );
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

      // FAIL 2
      MyActivity.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
      );

      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Some solutions below have done the trick for me. But I'd like to note that it took me a while to solve this because I was using a ScrollView. Solution for that situation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100831/stop-scrollview-from-setting-focus-on-edittext

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use a xml attribute,

```
android:cursorVisible
```

or you can do it in code with this method.

```
 setCursorVisible(boolean).
```

Comment: This fixed it. It also does the right thing by revealing the cursor when the keyboard is open. It only hides the cursor when you are not editing it.

Comment: WIsh I could give more up votes as I found 10 other complicated answers that didn't work before finding this one.  Thanks.

Comment: I have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677895/saving-an-edittext-to-bitmap ----- With this solution,pin hidden too! But i wanna hide only vertical blink line.

Comment: uhm, it does indeed hides the cursor, but the Editext remains highlited (coloured)

Comment: @JoJo if I use the `android:cursorVisible="false"` attribute it would remove the cursor in both, when the keyboard is open and when not. How did you get it to do what you wrote? And show the cursor only when you are editing it?

Comment: This in any case should not be the answer!

Comment: For me, it removes the blinking line completely, weather I have focus or not

Comment: It not just doesn't resolve the problem but also creates another one..

Answer (score 21):

Use the below code to remove the focus from the EditText

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(URLText.getWindowToken(), 0); 
                    editText.setFocusable(false);
                    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: searching from last 2 days... getting lots of solutions.. nothing worked... your solution is excellent.. ty

Comment: What is URLText?

Comment: Not working in my device Huawei P9 Lite, Google Pinyin Input.

Comment: use getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getWindowToken() instead of URLText.getWindowsToken()

Answer (score 10):

Here is my custom EditText which detect whether keyboard is showing & automatically remove focus when keyboard is hidden

```
/**
 * Created by TheFinestArtist on 9/24/15.
 */
public class KeyboardEditText extends EditText {

    public KeyboardEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public KeyboardEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public KeyboardEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener l) {
        super.setOnTouchListener(l);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        if (listener != null)
            listener.onStateChanged(this, true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (listener != null)
                listener.onStateChanged(this, false);

            // Hide cursor
            setFocusable(false);

            // Set EditText to be focusable again
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }

    /**
     * Keyboard Listener
     */
    KeyboardListener listener;

    public void setOnKeyboardListener(KeyboardListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface KeyboardListener {
        void onStateChanged(KeyboardEditText keyboardEditText, boolean showing);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working. Method `onKeyPreIme` don't called.

Comment: @rkyr why? it's working for me, I've tried several devices

Comment: @KirillVashilo, can't say now. It's been awhile since I faced that issue. Probably on KitKat device

Comment: This is the real answer to the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

After several attempts this is what worked best for me:

```
EditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId,
          KeyEvent keyEvent) { //triggered when done editing (as clicked done on keyboard)
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
          editText.clearFocus();
        }
        return false;
      }
    });
```

Comment: but if the user close keyboard by pressing back and don't pressed on done ?

Comment: You can override the onbackpressed() method

Comment: `onBackPressed` does not get called when you press the back button while soft keyboard is visible

Answer (score 2):

Fail 0:

Calling .requestFocus() on some layout element is not enough if the element is not focusable in touch mode. If you want to set the focus to a view or Button you have to call

```
.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

first or set it in your .xml

Answer (score 0):

For removing cursor

```
editText.isCursorVisible = false
```

And for gaining cursor visibilty when user click the edit text or it gets fouc cia imeOptions from other edit text, set this in onCreate

```
editText.setOnClickListener {
    binding.etFatherInLaw.isCursorVisible = true
}

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(object:View.OnFocusChangeListener{
    override fun onFocusChange(view: View?, hasFocus: Boolean) {
      binding.etFatherInLaw.isCursorVisible = hasFocus
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

if you dont want it to be editable at all i'd say do the below;

```
EditText orgid; 
orgid.setText(user.getOrgId());
orgid.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

For Kotlin users... I borrowed the best solution from @Sharone Lev but I had to add some coroutine delay or, for some reason, the EditText that is clearing its focus will stop the keyboard from dismissing.

```
someEditText.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->

         when(actionId){
            EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE->{

                //NOTE:wait few milliseconds before dismissing
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    delay(500)
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                        someEditText.clearFocus()
                    }
                }
            }
            else->{
                Log.w("TAG", "another action id ${actionId}")
            }
        }

        false
    }
```