# Saving an edittext to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, save

I am saving my layout to a bitmap, which contains an ImageView and an EditText.

I am using this code:

```
public void saveToImage(RelativeLayout content){

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(content.getWidth(), content.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    content.layout(0, 0, content.getLayoutParams().width, content.getLayoutParams().height);
    content.draw(c);


    try{
        File file,f = null;                    
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
            {  
                 file =new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TTImages_cache");
                 if(!file.exists())
                {
                  file.mkdirs();

                 } 
                 f = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+file.separator+ "filename"+".png");
            }
          FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(f);                                   
          bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
          ostream.close();

         } 


         catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

However the image I save looks like this:

[image: Layout-to-bitmap]

I would like to remove the underlined text and the text cursor in the edittext when saving the bitmap. Is that possible?

Comment: add this line: this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); your saveToImage() method.

Comment: Unfortunately the blinking cursor is also displayed when the keyboard is not :(

Comment: @deimos1988 Did you solved your problem?!

Comment: for disabling the blinking cursor you can use editText.setCursorVisible(false) while capturing the bitmap

Answer (score 0):

To remove the blinking cursor before saving the bitmap you can do

```
editText.setCursorVisible(false);
```

And then set it back to `true` again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove both `underline` and `cursor` when you start capturing the layout. You can remove the underline by:

```
yourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

and the cursor by:

```
yourEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
```

It would be better if you disable the cursor inside your `saveToImage` method by:

```
public void saveToImage(RelativeLayout content){
    yourEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
       ....
       ....
    //your code for saving the layout
}
```

and then after the layout is saved in the memory, just reset the `yourEditText` to show the cursor.

```
public void saveToImage(RelativeLayout content){
    //your code for saving the layout
       ....
       ....
    yourEditText.setCursorVisible(true);
}
```