# How to stop scrolling screen to top on selection of spinner in android

Tags: android, scroll, android-spinner, android-scrollview

I am using spinner in scroll view, when I do selection of spinner, scroll view is scrolling to top of screen. Is there any way to prevent this scroll?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are mis-diagnosing your problem. I have never experienced it and I have numerous scrollable screens with spinners that do not exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: Were you able to determine the cause of this?  I have this occurring now, but not with all spinners.

Comment: @Mark : No still did not get any solution. I have one scrollable screen with  many spinners, when I select item of one of the spinners at that time screen scrolls to top of screen. Post here if you find any solution. Thanks.

Comment: check my answer on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328592/spinner-dropdown-list-is-jumping-while-scrolling/55214793#55214793

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All

For above my issue I have set one property for scrollview in xml.

android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"

And it has worked for me like a charm.

I have found solution here

[Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2680077/1556997

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Hi, i m also facing exact issue, i tried like this in my scroll view  but no luck :(. can you please tell how you fixed. I m trying in ICS 4.0 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">.

Comment: Hi, CAA, noppe i was not able to solve this. If we use Actionbarsherlock, its not allowed. I checked with jakewarthon, he also suggested we cant use the internal spinner of actionbarsherlock. so i just thought of keeping default one. Thanks ill check ur answer

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" does not work with my ScrollView and I can't find more information to fix this issue ...

Comment: Old post, still up to date. I've been stuck with RecyclerView with the same issue - spinner as recyclerview item, change spinner selection causes recyclerview to scroll. This solves the issue.

Comment: please check this link, related scrollview.setOnTouchListener(), this fixed my issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/8101614/2164477