# Spinner dropdown list is jumping while scrolling

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

Why is my spinner jumping while scrolling? I'm simply doing following:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(v.getContext(), layout, textViewId, new ArrayList<String>());
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(layoutDropdown);
adapter.addAll(<DATA>);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
```

As long as the dropdown is small, everything works fine but if it gets larger and scrollable, I see that it jumps around while scrolling. Why?

I'm not changing the selection or data while scrolling, so I'm surprised that this happens in such an easy setup. Any ideas how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your adapter?

Comment: The adapter code is simple and is already added to my question.

Comment: Do you have any background processes going? Have you found different behavior in different devices/different OS versions? Are you using the support appcompat library?

Comment: I have a background service running, but scrolling a list with images is working smooth (so it's not a smoothness issue because of this), it's just the spinner popup that makes problem. And yes, I'm using appcompat in my app (v26.1.0). As the gif shows, it's not skipping frames, it's jumping to top while scrolling down for example...

Comment: @prom85 Did you find any solution?

Comment: No. I use a dialog for long lists. Sadly I could not reproduce this issue in a small project ever...

Comment: Just ran into this. My spinner had a style with parent "ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" applied; removing the style from the <Spinner> fixed the issue in my case.

Comment: Is there any solution to this? It looks really strange, can't be that only solution is to go with Dialogs...

Comment: I also recently ran into this issue, Problem is that it jumps in one screen ut when I make a similar screen with the same layout there t is completely fine!

Comment: Same for me. I have a complex demo, where I can't reproduce this behaviour but in another app I just have this problem...

Comment: I have the same issue, in another project the same code with the same list works perfectly well without any glitch and in the other it jumps when scrolled. Same adapter, same spinner, same layout is used in both. The only difference I could think of is that I am using *androidX* in the glitchy project. Are you all using AndroidX?

Comment: I am using android x, but had this issue already before moving to android x

Comment: @prom85 check my answer below

Answer (score 7):

I was faced with this.

Problem is **anroidx** update libs

UPDATE: as Bill Bunting comment "alpha04" is ok now

Resolve by revert version appcompat from **"alpha02/alpha03"** up to **"alpha04"**

***implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'***

or better

***implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'*** -> for more stable

Comment: appears to be fixed in 1.1.0-alpha4 for me.

Comment: Facing the same issue, but I couldn't download 1.1.0-alpha4. Workaround: spinnerMode="dialog"

Comment: Try this implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

Answer (score 0):

This is a very annoying, but known [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124274573) fixed in 1.1.0-alpha04 of appcompat, as per the release notes [Fixed AppCompatSpinnerscrolling in dropdown mode](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.1.0-alpha04)