# Android Spinner jumps to previous selected positions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner, android-xml

I am using AppCompatSpinner to show the list of states. Initially, I saved the first position item. Then After if I click the spinner and try to scroll slowly that time it goes to the previous position. if I scroll little fast it's working. During slow scroll and long press on the spinner, list item creates a problem.Can anybody know how to resolve this issue? here is my spinner.

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/stateSpinner"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:theme="@style/SpinnerStyle"/>


       val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
        context,
        R.layout.spinner_item, stateList
    )

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item)
    stateSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>, view: View, i: Int, l: Long) {
            viewModelOffice.officeSelectedState.set(stateList.get(i))

        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>) {
        }
    }
    stateSpinner.adapter = adapter
    stateSpinner.setSelection(selectedPosition)
}
```

In theme, I am just setting the colors.minimum version of the app is 21. Any Help will be Appreciated.

Comment: show your adapter code

Comment: @Bipin can u please check now

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Try to rephrase and provide more context and code.

Comment: @shkschneider 
I have a spinner with a Long list of items. What I noticed is that whenever I try to scroll the spinner items slowly, it suddenly takes me back to the top of the spinner selection. I'm just using a standard Spinner with a simple ArrayAdapter. It's not really an issue, but it's kinda annoying that whenever a user would scroll slowly, the selection resets all the way to the top. You can fling the list, but if you scroll slowly, keeping your finger on the screen, it scrolls back up to the top of the list.

Comment: I'm facing same issue. I guess the issue come with *androidx*. But still not find the way...

Comment: Any progress on this? i have the same problem. Same code before android x did not do this.

Comment: @mike_x_ see the answer below

Comment: @HoaNguyen below answer solved my issuse

Comment: @karthikeyan thanks, it's my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328592/spinner-dropdown-list-is-jumping-while-scrolling/55214793#55214793.
Missing update status for your toppic

Answer (score 4):

Finally it is worked for me

Problem is anroidx update libs

Resolve by revert version appcompat from "alpha02/alpha03" back to "alpha01"

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'

or better

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' -> for more stable

Comment: Same here. Because I'm `minSdkVersion 21` anyway, I just created a new class `NoSupportSpinner extends Spinner`, to avoid the broken `AppCompatSpinner`