# Scroll view flicker during view inflate

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have list of elements in scroll view. When clicking the element, I need to load data from server and inflate it in the clicked view. The data I fetch from server has variable heights. So I cannot fix the view height.

My problem is,

1- I click a view to fetch data.

2- I will be showing progressbar during server fetch.

3- I scroll down to view other data. In the mean time, if the the server fetch is success I will set the data. It will automatically adjust the scrollview. Since the scroll height is changed, the data I am viewing suddenly scrolls down.

I need to lock the scroll to the content I am viewing. I tried this solution, [Stop ScrollView from setting focus on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100831/stop-scrollview-from-setting-focus-on-edittext) but this is not working during scroll.

Pleas advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have dynamic content content in your view then why you not using list view?

Comment: In listview too there will be similar issue. Moreover I have multiple webiviews in the view which caused me loading/flickering issues

Comment: So u mean u having diffrent webview inside scroll view redirecting to different url?

Comment: yes. i will show progressbar of fixed height during loading

Comment: Then you must use list view....and post the url which you trying load...i will check that whether it is still flickering with list view or not

Comment: Or if you already tried with list view then share the code of adapter...and tell how u adding and updating the adapter

Comment: I will be fetching html content and load content through javascript. I do not want to recycle the view. So I switched to scroll view

Comment: Ohhh...then i think you should share your code...then only i can proposed some other some solutions

Comment: I have shared a demo code explaining my scenario -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0tVlqj4uamAd3A0Q2FPd0xXOXc/view?usp=sharing   .