# RecyclerView: Disable scrolling caused by change in focus

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, focus

**TL;DR** I have a `RecyclerView` of `EditText`s. When the user is focused on `EditText #1` and taps on `EditText #2`, I want `EditText #2` to get focus but I don't want the `ReyclerView` to scroll. How can I achieve this?

---

I'm trying to work with a `RecyclerView` populated with a bunch of `EditText`s. When I'm focused on one `EditText` and I click on another, the `RecyclerView` scrolls so that the second is at the top of the screen. I want to disable this auto-scrolling from the `RecyclerView`, but I still want the user to be able to scroll, and I still want the second `EditText` to be focused on so the user can start typing. How can I achieve this?

I've already tried the following solutions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8101614/4077294, but with a `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener`. I called `recyclerView.requestFocusFromTouch` in `onInterceptTouchEvent`.

  - **Behavior:** Scrolled to the top of the tapped `EditText` all the time.
- Clearing the focus from any `EditText` whenever it was focused on, via

  ```
  editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFocusChange(View v, bool hasFocus) {
          if (hasFocus) {
              v.clearFocus();
          }
      }
  });
  ```

  - **Behavior:** The keyboard never showed up, and the `RecyclerView` still scrolled to the top.

Disabling scrolling altogether as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531091/how-to-disable-recyclerview-scrolling) is not acceptable because I still want the user to be able to scroll.

Comment: Try this :  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|stateHidden" in manifest

Comment: Can you please post what worked for you? I'm also interested in knowing.

Comment: @HBrooks There hasn't been an answer yet.

Comment: see `requestChildRectangleOnScreen` you can override it either at view or layout manager level

Comment: @pskink Can you give an example of how I would use it?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8JLSMkF7

Comment: @pskink Thanks. I'll try what you've posted when I'm able to work on my app again, and let you know if it works.

Comment: the longer version (with rect intersection checks) is for cases when you could navigate your `RV` using the D-pad, so you could just start with the shorter one (only returning false)

Comment: @pskink Thank you so much. I tried your solution with just returning false, and it worked perfectly. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: but remember when using the short form (just return false) if you use arrow keys (dpad, hardware keyboard and some soft keyboards also have arrows) you can simply lose your cursor and go outside the bounds of your `RV` - thats why the form with some checks could be better

Comment: @pskink Oh, I didn't realize that. Will make a note to come back to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I ended up with this solution from @pskink:

```
recylerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean requestChildRectangleOnScreen(RecyclerView parent, View child, Rect rect, boolean immediate) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

It seems to work perfectly, but @pskink has mentioned that this could have problems when using arrow keys. He's posted another solution here: https://pastebin.com/8JLSMkF7. If you have problems with the above solution, you may try the alternative solution at the link. For now, I'm sticking with the one I just posted here.

**UPDATE**

Since support-library v25.3.0 you should also override another [requestChildRectangleOnScreen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#requestChildRectangleOnScreen(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.view.View,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20boolean,%20boolean)) method in LayoutManager:

```
@Override
public boolean requestChildRectangleOnScreen(RecyclerView parent, View child, Rect rect, boolean immediate, boolean focusedChildVisible) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

RecyclerView will scroll to focused item.
Try recyclerView.setFocusable(false).
This worked for me.