# How to prevent a scrollview from scrolling to a webview after data is loaded?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

So I have a fascinating problem.  Despite the fact that I'm not manually or programmatically scrolling my view, my WebView is being automatically scrolled to after the data inside it loads.

I've got a fragment in a viewpager.  When I first load the pager, it works as expected and everything is shown.  But once I "flip the page" the data loads and the WebView pops up to the top of the page, hiding the views above it, which is undesirable.

Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

My layout looks like such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:text="Some Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/article_title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_Seperator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@color/text"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/article_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_link"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="View Full Article"
            android:textColor="@color/article_title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I'm also not giving focus to anything.  By default, it seems to automatically scroll to the WebView after it has loaded.  How do I prevent this?

Comment: why exactly do you need the ScrollView as a WebView is scrollable?

Comment: To keep some aspects out of the webview instead of rendering them as HTML.  For speed and quality.

Comment: mjp66 has the best answer - may be you should accept his answer

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can simply add this to your LinearLayout: android:focusableInTouchMode="true". It works for me.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: Works without side effects!

Answer (score 269):

I had the same problem, after hours of trying several ideas, what finally worked for me was simply adding the `descendantFocusability` attribute to the ScrollView's containing LinearLayout, with the value `blocksDescendants`. In your case:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
```

Haven't had the problem reoccur since.

Comment: Does this have any negative impact on the accessibility of these controls?

Comment: Note that if there are any child views like EditText, this method will cause them to become uneditable.

Comment: This question/answer doesn't come up when you search for the words ScrollView Webview autoscroll, and it should.  Maybe this comment will help!  Had the same issue with using a WebViewFragment and didn't find this question even after lots of searching until I posted my own question (now deleted).

Comment: Good answer. It would be good if you can explain View priorities for taking focus in android

Comment: Working on a Xamarin.Android project, had auto scroll trouble in a scrollview with multiple gridviews, populated asynchronously with downloaded images. This solution worked so perfectly I had trouble to believe it at first sight and had to test it again.

Comment: The very same issue happens for Ads in a `RecyclerView` as well. Your solution works in that case as well :)

Comment: I think it's because when onLayout() is called in any ScrollView, it checks to see if any child has focus. If they do, the ScrollView will automatically scroll to that child. When new things load inside the ScrollView, I believe it somehow takes the focus, and that's what causes the problem.

Comment: I had a recycler  view (A), inside a recycler view (B) and the page was jumping when the data was put into recycler view (B). I tried overriding the laymanager for recycler  view (A) and disabling vertical scrolling and it was a solution, but I needed to enable it after the data was entered into recycler view (B) but I got it working. Messy fix. This fix has saved me so much hassle. Cheers

Answer (score 27):

You should create new class extend ScrollView, then Override requestChildFocus:

```
public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {

    @Override 
    public void requestChildFocus(View child, View focused) { 
        if (focused instanceof WebView ) 
           return;
        super.requestChildFocus(child, focused);
    }
}
```

Then in your xml layout, using:

```
<MyScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background" >
```

That works for me. The ScrollView will not auto scroll to the WebView anymore.

Comment: Also needed constructors: 
 `public ExtendedScrollView(Context context) {
  super(context);
 }
 
 public ExtendedScrollView( Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
  super(context, attributeSet);
 }
 
 public ExtendedScrollView( Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);
 }`

Answer (score 6):

Adding these line in main layout solves the problem

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
<com.ya.test.view.MyScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably there are people who have the same problem I was having, so I'll help out.

I was trying to put **android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"** in my main ScrollView as following:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">
    /*my linearlayout or whatever to hold the views */
```

and it wasn't working, so I had to make a RelativeLayout the parent of the ScrollView, and place the **android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"** in the parent aswell.

So I solved it doing the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
/*my linearlayout or whatever to hold the views */
```

Answer (score 0):

I added: `android:overScrollMode="never"` in my ScrollView and set the height to `wrap_content`.

My view was very complex as it was legacy code with LinearLayout inside LinearLayout inside LinearLayout.

This helped me, hope it will help someone else too!

Answer (score -2):

I had to use the fully qualified name for MyScrollView, otherwise I got an inflate exception.

```
<com.mypackagename.MyScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background" >
```