# Is there an alternative to NestedScrollView for use with a WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-support-library, android-design-library

When using a `WebView` inside a `NestedScrollView` there are a few issues. The main one I'm fighting is that sites which load more content as you scroll down don't work well, for example vimeo.com. Also setting the view to `LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE` doesn't work, probably for the same reason, it basically crashes because of the height. So, is there an alternative to the `NestedScrollView` if I want to use `CoordinatorLayout` in order to collapse the toolbar when the user scrolls inside the `WebView`?

My code is below. In order to reproduce the issue just load vimeo.com and scroll to the bottom.

activity_scrolling.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.webviewnestedscroll.ScrollingActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

ScrollingActivity.java

```
package com.webviewnestedscroll;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        settings.setAppCachePath(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setSaveFormData(true);
        //view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

        view.loadUrl("http://vimeo.com");



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scrolling, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I've already tried wrapping it around a `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc. I've also tried setting the sizes to a specific number.

Comment: It looks like a bug in the Support library. Worth to report to Google.

Comment: I've reported it already but haven't heard anything and I've seen a lot of support library webview related bugs with zero comments or acknowledgements so I'm just trying to find an alternative.

Comment: I think there should be a custom NestScrollWebView , not NestedScrollView and WebView.

Answer (score 0):

As i [referred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14632456/1318946), You should try to add `LinearLayout` with `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` like:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.webviewnestedscroll.ScrollingActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

      </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

May it will helpful to you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks but it has the same issue. If I go all the way to the bottom on vimeo.com the page doesn't realize I went all the way down and there is also a ton of white space at the bottom.